# local.xml added to Magento layout directory but is not being applied and is ignored

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.8, magento-layout-xml

I'm using Alan Storm's advice from: [Specify Category specific layout updates without using Magento's administration dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021517/specify-category-specific-layout-updates-without-using-magentos-administration/6022085#6022085) using several category specific layout updates inside of my local.xml.

I have validated the xml, and it is being returned as valid xml. I have enabled mage developer mode to on to report an error and have looked at the exception logs to see if something is wrong, however no luck.

here is my local.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * local.xml
 *
 * Local layout modifications for our local theme
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     my_theme_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011 Magebase.
 */
-->
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
        <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />  <!--the dog-->
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout" />  <!--back to school-->
    </reference>
</default>
<reviews>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="header"/>
        <remove name="footer"/>
    </reference>
</reviews>
<review_product_list>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="header"/>
        <remove name="footer"/>
    </reference>
</review_product_list>

<CATEGORY_11> <!-- cat 5 or cat 6 -->
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="page.brand" template="page/brand.phtml" />
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="page/gourmet.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="filter_menu" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
                </block>
          </reference> 
</CATEGORY_11>

<CATEGORY_12><!--cat 7 or cat 8 -->
            <reference name="content">
               <block type="core/template" name="page.brand" template="page/brand.phtml" />
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="page/toiletries.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="filter_menu" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </reference>
</CATEGORY_12>

<CATEGORY_9> <!--cat 4 or cat5 -->
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="page.brand" template="page/brand.phtml" />
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="page/fashion.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="filter_menu" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
                </block>
          </reference>
</CATEGORY_9>

<CATEGORY_6> <!--cat_11 cat_3 -->
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="page.brand" template="page/brand.phtml" />
                <block type="core/template" name="page.flip" template="page/flip.phtml" />
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="page/accessories.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="filter_menu" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
                </block>
          </reference>
</CATEGORY_6>

<CATEGORY_10> <!-- cat 6 or 7 -->
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="page.brand" template="page/brand.phtml" />
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="page/lifestyle.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="filter_menu" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
                </block>
          </reference>
</CATEGORY_10>

</layout>
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: its worth noting the category page shows blank, as there is no content set for the cms page in the admin panel

Comment: Does this `<CATEGORY_11>` exist ?

Comment: Cleared cache for that.

Comment: hi, yes all of the categories exist and cache is disabled.

Comment: check if your xml file has not got corrupted i.e some tag got missed etc. is this  <remove name="breadcrumbs"/> removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking someone and after thinking about it, it turns out I was viewing cms pages, and those category layout handle only updates category pages not cms pages, i tested it on a category page and it works fine. so if i want those updates to happen on cms pages, i would have to use cms handles.

Comment: and apparently there are no cms specific handles like there are for categories (except the home page).

Answer (score 0):

Under System -> Configuration go to Design. Make sure the current package name and layout fields are correctly setup according to your theme.

Comment: the current package name is set to "cn" and the layout field was blank but i added "cn" in there as well but it didnt work.

Comment: Please write your directory structure ie design -> frontend -> etc