# Filters showing up for all category products, rather than category specific filters from layered navigation

Tags: php, magento, filter, magento-1.8, magento-layout-xml

Using magento 1.7.2, i was able to load products for a specific category on my cms pages using the specific category layout handle  in the local.xml file, and the layered navigation filters would show only for that specific category.

Now however, in magento 1.8.1, my local.xml is always ignored, and using the same snippets from local.xml in the admin panel for layout xml updates, the updates work, but the filters that are showing up are for all categories and not the specific category, even though isAnchor is set to no on that specific category.

I have posted this question on SO about how to keep my local.xml from being ignored: [local.xml added to Magento layout directory but is not being applied and is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924964/local-xml-added-to-magento-layout-directory-but-is-not-being-applied-and-is-igno)

The filters that are being retrieved for my specific category is the same in the catalog view.phtml file using:

```
$this->getFilters()
```

However because I'm not using category handles in the local.xml, the filters are not being picked up for the specific category, rather, its using all categories.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Posted an answer on your other question, see if that helps